# Hourglass pointer launching a nemo quicklist sub-item from UnityLauncher

Tags: unity, launcher, quicklists, nemo

Running raring 13.04 I meet a strange behaviour (non-blocking). When I launch a home subfolder (e.g. Music) from the nemo launcher, the windows opens fine but I always get the hourglass pointer for 15s, after which the pointer becomes normal, whether I keep the window opened or I close it before the 15s laptime.

I don't use cinnamon (not installed), just nemo v1.7.2 from synaptic/software center.

When I run nemo Music from a terminal or from the Alt+F2 prompt, I don't get this hourglass. I don't get it neither when I just left-click the nemo parent icon. I don't get this behaviour neither with LibreOffice icon sub-items.

I tried to specify the full path in ~/.local/share/applications/nemo.desktop (Exec=nemo /home/me/Music) with no change in behaviour.

Please, what does make this to happen?

Thank you

Comment: Although it is an old question, this recent answer (http://askubuntu.com/questions/744173/custom-right-click-action-in-unity-launcher-keeps-cursor-busy-for-20-seconds) is likely relevant.